# mv directory and contents to new directory

Tags: mv

I have a directory:
    `/var/lib/mysql/test_db/`
which contains numerous files that make up the `test_db` database

I have now created a new directory:
    `/var/lib/mysql/data/`

I am trying to move the `test_db` directory and it's contents into the `data` directory.

I've tried various commands revolving around

```
sudo mv /var/lib/mysql/test_db/ /var/lib/mysql/data/test_db/
```

But I keep getting the error:

```
mv: cannot move /var/lib/mysql/test_db/ to /var/lib/msyql/data/test_db/: No such file or directory
```

But if I run:
    `ls -lah`

I get

```
drwxrwxrwx  2 root  root    32K Mar 27 15:58 test_db
drwxrwxrwx  3 mysql mysql  4.0K Mar 30 10:51 data
```

which from what I can tell means they are both directories, and therefore both exist.

As you can see I have changed permissions on them both (`chmod 777 test_db`), but that didn't work.

What am I missing?

Comment: you are missing the subdirectory `/var/lib/msyql/data` create it or use roaima's answer

Comment: an alternative is to hardlink the files ... then you can use `cp -al ...`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Remove the target database directory and move the `test_db` directory itself. (This will implicitly move its contents, too.)

```
sudo rmdir /var/lib/mysql/data/test_db
sudo mv /var/lib/mysql/test_db /var/lib/mysql/data
```

Generally you don't need to provide a trailing slash on directory names.

Reading your comments, if you find that you're still getting a "no such file or directory" error, it may be that your source directory, `test_db` has already been moved into the target `test_db` directory (giving you `/var/lib/mysql/data/test_db/test_db/...`). If this is the case then the `rmdir` above will also fail with a "no such file or directory" error. Fix it with this command, and then re-run the two at the top of this answer:

```
sudo mv /var/lib/mysql/data/test_db/test_db /var/lib/mysql
```

Comment: cheers, that must be the only variation I didn't try. I guess because I was using `mv` to rename files I got in the habit of always declaring it in both parts of the `mv` statement.

Answer (score 12):

Your command:

```
sudo mv /var/lib/mysql/test_db/ /var/lib/mysql/data/test_db/
```

is for moving `/var/lib/mysql/test_db/` *inside* `/var/lib/mysql/data/test_db/`, and end up with `/var/lib/mysql/data/test_db/test_db/`. But as `/var/lib/mysql/data/test_db/` does not exist, you're getting an error.

You should run:

```
sudo mv /var/lib/mysql/test_db/ /var/lib/mysql/data/
```

to have `/var/lib/mysql/test_db/` moved inside `/var/lib/mysql/data/`.